# Where should I put code which calls Oracle OCI?

Tags: c++, oracle-call-interface, proc

I want to retrieve data from oracle data base from a c++ program ,can one suggest me which is better option either

oracle call  interface(OCI) or C/C++ pre compiler(Pro *C/C++)  and also tell me the difference between both . Thank you.

Edit from comments:
Should I put the OCI-calling code in .cpp files, or PreCompiler (.pc/.pcpp) files?

Comment: OCI is a bit of software you can call from your own code to talk to an Oracle database. A PreCompiler is....part of a compiler. Your question is like saying that you want a drink and should you use a glass of water or a car?

Comment: but instead .c or .cpp files i can write .pc or .pcpp to connect database? my requirement is i have a file with comma seperator(seperator may varry) and i need to extract the file and insert into orcale database? which is better option either OCI in cpp file or .pc/.pcpp file?

Comment: I have no iesa as I'm not a C++ programmer. However I will edit your question so it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First an explanation of both options:

- Pro*C/C++ lets you write SQL statements directly in your C/C++ code as if the language had been extended by new keywords like SELECT and INSERT. Just like ABAP or Linq. This effect is gained by preprocessing your mix of embedded SQL and C/C++ with a a so called precompiler. It translated all that embedded SQL into lots of C code that calls an internal Oracle library named "SQLLIB". The result is plain C/C++ code and can be fed to your standard C/C++ compiler.
- OCI is simply a C interface / API to be called from C/C++ code. No preprocessing magic, just C/C++.

Pro & Contra:

- Embedded SQL makes the SQL easily readable and reduces the amount of code to write. All that recurring boilerplate code is hidden by the precompiler. That's nice. But the precompiler introduces a new build step with new problems: for example the precompiler expects the embedded SQL in a specific order all in one file. Plain C would allow to split it up and move the functions around. Embedded SQL introduces new language rules to obey.
- There is no faster way to access the DB than OCI. I assume SQLLIB calls OCI, but that means you have one additional indirection over OCI. It is a plain C API, no new language rules to learn. But it obscures the SQL within function calls and all that C syntax.

Which is better? It depends.